# How can I update the default stock browser (com.android.browser)?

Tags: updates, stock-browser

I have version 2.3.3 of the stock android browser on my phone.  I know there are newer versions out that support features that I want which are not available in 2.3.3.  However, I do not see any upgrades available, and in fact the stock browser does not even show up in the Google Play store.

I figure I probably need to manually install from somewhere, but where do I find the necessary files and how do I perform the upgrade?  Note: I am not interested in upgrading to a newer version of Android.

Comment: Firefox mobile supports Android 2.2 and above is you're stuck with an older version of Android and needs features that aren't available in older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=34132038&postcount=9). It has an APK for a 4.2 AOSP browser.

**NOTE:** Install at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks! There aren't really any install instructions... in searching my system I see `data/data/com.android.browser` and `/system/app/Browser.apk`.  I currently need the browser to replace what WebView is using, will it replace that too?